# How do I move a parented object hierarchy to world origin

Tags: transforms, parent

I have carefully created and parented object hierarchy. I did this for ease of moving the ensemble of parts in the scene. But I am pulling my hair out doing what I thought was a trivial afterthought: move the ensemble to world origin.

What is the magic incantation for something so simple?

Comment: Try Alt+P > Keep Transformation

Comment: Do you want to snap the parent to (0, 0, 0)? Do you want to unparent the children without changing their position? Do you want to reset origins to (0, 0, 0)? Please clariy "move the ensemble to world origin". You could just select the parent and G-move it in 3D space.

Comment: I want to move the hierarchy to the origin. Should be simple.

Comment: Normally this is done by selecting the root of the hierarchy and setting translation to 0,0,0. No way to do that in Blender. Grrrrr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the parent of all the hierarchy, and in the object panel, manually set its location to 0,0,0. The shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

It should keep the position of the children relative to the parent.

Comment: Laurent, I have select the root in the outliner. I select the Object panel. I see no place to type 0,0,0.

Comment: It's under the Transform section, here you have have 3 sub-sections : Location, Rotation, Scale. 
You should be able to type 0, in each of the 3 numeric fields under "location". (respectively for location X, location Y and location Z).

(http://www.kiwimage.com/images/blender-transform.png)

Comment: Note, I imported the model into Unity and this is a breeze.